# Wrong scale in Print layout mode

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, print-composer, scale

[image]I´m using qgis 3.16 and have the folowing Problem:
If i´m in the primary Window the scale on the bottom of the scrren shows me a correct value, but if i switch into the Printlayout mode the value of scale is wrong and about 10 times higher. I added to my project a shapefile and a few maps to work with.
So far i didn´t tryed anything because i´m quite lost. I read in another article that it might help to change the CRS, but i have no idea where to do it. How to fix the wrong scale?

In the picture you can see the scale bar shows 3750km which is wrong, it must be about 700 meters.

Comment: Which scale is wrong in the Prinlayout - in the item properties? Can you add a screenshot? Please add some more information: what is your project CRS (bottom right corner of QGIS main window)? Why do you think the scale is wrong in Printlayout?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I added a picture to the post. The CRS is ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N, it also says Unknown CRS

Comment: Have you linked the scale to the map? You can see that if you click the Maßstab in the Elemente and then check Elemeneigenschaften. There your scale should be linked to the "Karte 1"

Comment: Yes the scalebar is linked to the map in the print layoutmode.